# How to format the yaml file to a csv format?

Tags: shell, awk, yaml, jq, yq

I have used the yq command to format a yaml file:

**cat includelist.yml |yq -r '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList'**

output:

```
---
ProductLine:
  ProductLineName: AAAAA
  ADO_FeedsList:
  - ProjectName: IT
    FeedsName:
    - test
    - test2
  - ProjectName: organization
    FeedsName:
    - hello
    - world
---
ProductLine:
  ProductLineName: BBBBB
  ADO_FeedsList:
  - ProjectName: Fin
    FeedsName:
    - good
    - aaaa
  - ProjectName: organization
    FeedsName:
    - bbb
    - ccc
```

Could somebody give me some suggestion,I don't known how to convert to csv format.

My question: how to convert the content to the following format:

IT,test

IT,test2

orginazation,hello

orginazation,world

Fin,good

Fin,aaaa

organization,bbb

organization,ccc

---

Thanks a ton.

Comment: yq eval -o json includelist.yml |jq -r '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[]|"\(.ProjectName),\(.FeedsName[])"'

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) anyway, you could directly output CSV using `-o csv` (instead of using `-o json` and calling `jq`):

```bash
yq -o csv '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[] | [.ProjectName] + (.FeedsName[] | [.])' includelist.yml
```

```
IT,test
IT,test2
organization,hello
organization,world
Fin,good
Fin,aaaa
organization,bbb
organization,ccc
```

Comment: Thanks for your profession command.It's very great for me.

Thanks for your patience at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert to JSON, then use the jq command.

```
yq eval -o json includelist.yml | \
    jq -r '.ProductLine.ADO_FeedsList[]|"\(.ProjectName),\(.FeedsName[])"'
```